# How to change the given below json array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array in the following format:

```
[{"country":"Algeria"},{"country":"Africa"},{"country":"America"},{"country":"Libiya"}]
```

I need to change it as follows:

```
{"Algeria","Africa","America","Libiya"}
```

How do I do that using Jquery or JavaScript?

Comment: I have to second Rob's comment. I've provided an answer below assuming you were working in JavaScript, but that's not actually clear from your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: Using javascript or jquery

Comment: Thought so. At the moment, you have two possible JavaScript solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var myArray = [{"country":"Algeria"},{"country":"Africa"},{"country":"America"},{"country":"Libiya"}];
var myNewArray = [];
for (var item in myArray) {
    var country = myArray[item].country;
    myNewArray.push(country);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(myNewArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually have the wrong notation in your question. The end result you want should have square brackets (`[]`), not curly braces(`{}`). Curly braces indicate an object instead of an array but you are not using a key-value structure so the end-result you have above is actually invalid.

Instead it seems you want `["Algeria","Africa",America","Libiya"]` as the end-result.

Assuming you mean literally changing the array you have rather than creating a new one and assuming you are using JavaScript:

```
var arr = [{"country":"Algeria"},{"country":"Africa"},{"country":"America"},{"country":"Libiya"}], // declare your array upfront (but this could be a `JSON.parse()` call)
    i = 0, // counter
    l = arr.length; // limit/length of array

for (i; i < l; i += 1) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].country; // Replace object with value of country property.
}

// `arr` will now be `["Algeria","Africa",America","Libiya"]`
```

Of course you might want to introduce some checks to ensure that every element of the array has a property called `country` and some way to deal with that in the rewritten array. But I'll leave you with this for now, see how you get on. This should work if your array is valid to begin with.